# How I will get appAccountToken from StoreKit verifyReceipt api for legacy user?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am using StoreKit for my in app purchase monthly subscription . From first time I was sending `productId`, `quantity` and `atomically` for purchase api. I was getting `transaction_id` and `original_transaction_id`. But for some reason currently I need `appAccountToken` from apple verifyReciept api also . So I am sending `applicationUsername` when purchasing by purchase api and getting `appAccountToken` from verifyReceipt api.

But the problem is about legacy user support . How I will get `appAccountToken` or set `applicationUsername` for existing users because when they subscribed on that time there was no field named `applicationUsername`.
  now the question is how can I set applicationUsername for current subscribers?
 Any Idea about my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

*applicationUsername* has been available since iOS 7.0 see the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skmutablepayment/1506088-applicationusername

> But for some reason currently I need appAccountToken from apple verifyReciept api also

This is an optional property, StoreKit does not require you to set a value for either applicationUsername or appAccountToken.

Comment: yes I know this is optional. but for some logical change I need now this property . so actually I want to know is it possible now to set application username for previous users who have no application token ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard for us to do so.

Only when the subscribed users churned and buy in next turn can we send the new value in applicationUsername/appAccountToken.

But maybe we can do so in other ways, by using **KeyChain** or **CloudKit**, which something is also associated with AppleID. That means, both the receipt and KeyChain info are related with AppleID. When you sending the receipt from client, you may get the KeyChain info too. However, this way is not available for Server to Server notification.